# How to open the camera app on ios react native

Tags: react-native

Tell me how to open the camera app on react-native ios. The below code is not working

```
Linking.openURL("camera://")
```

Comment: Are. you using expo ?

Comment: cli, but if there is a solution for expo, I would like to see it too

Answer (score 0):

You can open the camera in expo using expo image picker library

here's the documentation for u.
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/#ios

Image picker library is also used in cli but with different imports and package installation command is different. Here's the link for u. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker

Comment: ImagePiker doesn't open the camera app, it just lets you take a single photo. need to open camera app via deep link